# Why do I get the same result regardless of which button I click?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to make a basic program that takes the values of two HTML input fields, and multiplies or divides them depending upon which button was clicked. At the moment, I'm just trying to alert the value of either the multiply or divide button via `document.getElementById()`.

However, at present it believes I have clicked the Multiply button, even if I click Divide.

Here is the HTML:

```
<form>
    <input type="text" placeholder="enter a number" id="numOne"/>
    <input type="text" placeholder="enter a number" id="numTwo"/>
    <br>
    <button id="M" onclick="calc()" value="Multiply">Multiply</button>   
    <button id="D" onclick="calc()" value="Divide">Divide</button>
</form>
```

and the JavaScript:

```
function calc() {
    if (document.getElementById('M').value === 'Multiply') {
        alert('You clicked multiply');
    } else if (document.getElementById('D').value === 'Divide') {
        alert('You clicked divide');
    }
}
```

I've tried to figure it out myself and look it up, and have found nothing.

Comment: Why would the value of the buttons ever change? Just use a different function for each button

Comment: There was no problem statement at all in this question. I have tried to guess at the nature of the problem from the code you've supplied, and from the answers given, and added that in. Feel free to edit it further, but remember that without a clear and unambiguous statement of an unexpected behaviour, questions will be put on hold here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add a different function for each button

```js
document.getElementById('M').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  
  var val1 = document.getElementById('numOne').value;
  var val2 = document.getElementById('numTwo').value;
  var answ = document.getElementById('answer');
  
  answ.value = val1 * val2;
});

document.getElementById('D').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  
  var val1 = document.getElementById('numOne').value;
  var val2 = document.getElementById('numTwo').value;
  var answ = document.getElementById('answer');
  
  answ.value = val1 / val2;
});
```

```html
<form>
  <input placeholder="enter a number" id="numOne" />
  <input placeholder="enter a number" id="numTwo" />
  <br>
  <button id="M">Multiply</button>
  <button id="D">Divide</button>
  <br><br>
  <input id="answer" />
</form>
```

Comment: Holy moly guys, thank you! Those responses came incredibly fast. It works completely fine now. Thanks for saving me from myself!

Comment: @frustratedFrankenstein Instead of writing two functions, you could also give the two buttons the same class and bind one function to the elements by class; then you could check the id with `this.id`.

Comment: Sure you could. You could do something like this instead -> https://jsfiddle.net/c30qLwb6/, I just wrote it a little different to make it easier to understand.

Answer (score 1):

The first `if` check (`if (document.getElementById('M').value === 'Multiply') {`) will always evaluate to `true` because the value of that button will always be "Multiply". You can either pass in an onclick parameter to `calc()` that tells the method what to do, or define separate methods for multiplying and dividing and call the respective ones `onclick`.

Answer (score 0):

This is working for first button because your both buttons have same function and first if statement check if M id has multiply and it does so it returns true and message multiply was clicked try using same class name to check value and then it will work. Or do it like this:

```js
function calc(thisValue) {
  if (thisValue === 'Multiply') {
      alert('You clicked multiply');
  } else if (thisValue === 'Divide') {
      alert('You clicked divide');
  }
}
```

```html
<form>
<input type="text" placeholder="enter a number" id="numOne"/>
<input type="text" placeholder="enter a number" id="numTwo"/>
    <br>
<button onclick="calc(this.value)" value="Multiply">Multiply</button>   
<button onclick="calc(this.value)" value="Divide">Divide</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You were checking a condition that would never change. The ID `M` will always  have the value `Multiply` and `D` will always have `Divide`.

You were probably thinking of looking dynamically at the ID of the button clicked. You can do this by passing the event object, and using `event.currentTarget` to get a reference to that element, then act based on the ID you find.

```js
function calc(event) {
  // Stop the form from submitting
  event.preventDefault();
  
  // Find which button was clicked.
  const btn = event.currentTarget;
  
  // Use the ID of btn to decide what to do
  switch (btn.id) {
  case "M":
    alert('You clicked multiply');
    break;
  case "D":
    alert('You clicked divide');
    break;
  }
}
```

```html
<form>
  <input type="text" placeholder="enter a number" id="numOne" />
  <input type="text" placeholder="enter a number" id="numTwo" />
  <br>
  <button id="M" onclick="calc(event)" value="Multiply">Multiply</button>
  <button id="D" onclick="calc(event)" value="Divide">Divide</button>
</form>
```